# Shortcut to a list of files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut

I have about 15 files in a very large solution that I'd like to be able to permanently have in some kind of popout panel that I can click to access them quickly. Is there any way to accomplish this within Visual Studio?

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to bookmark all the 15 files at the first line of each and navigate through the bookmarks in Visual Studio; or if you have Re-Sharper installed this makes it even easier, you just set re-sharper book marks and it gives you a little window of all the files.  Resharper -> navigate -> bookmarks ; you can set a shortcut for this window in REsharper settings if you want.